# Sum of comma separated string like 4,1,3 by O(n)

Tags: c++

4,1,3 is a string input and i need to find the sum of all the elements separated by comma and display all the sum separated by comma e.g 1+3=4,4+3=7,4+1=5 therefore final output should be 4,7,5 by O(n).
I have done this with O(n^2)

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    sum=0;
    if(s[i] != ',')
    {
        for(int j=size-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(s[j] != ',' && j!=i)

                sum = sum+(s[j]-48);

        }
        if(i == size-1)
        cout<<sum;
        else
        cout<<sum<<',';

    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: That looks like a statement.  Did you have a question?  Are you having a problem with your code?  Could you provide a [mcve] that shows whatever problem you are facing?  (I did not downvote.)

Comment: This was a question given to code in C++ and I'm unable to solve this question by O(n) complexity. Input is 4,1,3 and Output is 4,7,5? Constraint O(n).

Comment: Does the output have to be `4 7 5`.  What if it `5 4 7`?

Comment: @AmanPratapSingh At least [show us what you tried to solve that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and where exactly you're stuck with solving it with _O(n)_ time complexity.

Comment: Output also needs to be separated by comma in the given order 4,7,5 @NathanOliver

Comment: how are you able to solve it in anything else than O(n) ? Please show your code

Comment: @AmanPratapSingh _"but unable to do with O(n)"_ Isn't a precise problem description.  As mentioned, [edit] your question please with what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... We are not a homework solving community here and you've got enough comments on the style of your question. Further, your problem does not seem to be C++, but algorithmic. I Hope you learn from it for your next questions. But I find this interesting.
Here's an idea:

a) iterate all elements and calculate the sum of all elements  ->  O(n)

b) iterate all elements and put out (sum - element)  -> O(n)

O(n)+O(n) = O(n)